# How to test SQS DLQ without having to wait for visibilityTimeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function that is triggered by an SQS. This SQS redrives failed messages to a DLQ. I am trying to write an integration test that sends a broken event to lambda so it would throw an error and send the message back to SQS. I've set maximum receives to 1 so SQS should send it to the DLQ.

Problem is my visibilityTimeout is set to 70 seconds and I don't want to wait for that long in my test. I tried reducing the visibilityTimeout using using the SDK but I think it takes a while for the update to take effect which means I need to wait for it in my test and I am trying to avoid making the test take too long.

Is there a way to test the flow from SQS ---> Lambda ---> SQS ---> DLQ, without having to wait for visibilityTimeout?

Comment: Its not possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71148907/force-a-message-from-sqs-queue-to-its-dead-letter-queue